# Program Hosting - tunneling/NAT IPv4/IPv6 in either direction

Tags: c++, ipv6, nat, ipv4

I would like to state that I am not the developer of this program. I'm merely a user, and I'm curious if there's a way in the program itself to translate IPv6 to work with IPv4, or viceversa. Or if this is something that would need to be done via some 3rd party software. Because as it currently stands, if you have an IPv6 address you cannot have IPv4 users connect to you and vice versa.

For background reference, [Drawpile](https://drawpile.net) is written in C++ using the Qt framework, and is available on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. 
https://github.com/drawpile/Drawpile

Answer (score 2):

IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols. Not only the app needs to support them but the network does too. If a network only supports one of them there is nothing the app can do. There need to be servers that talk IPv4 to one side and IPv6 to the other so the users can communicate.

In some cases there are NAT64 servers provided by the network that can be used. In other cases the developers need to provide them themselves.

This is not 100% a programming question, but I think this answer may be useful to developers that are learning to deal with the current network environments.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that but I wasn't sure. Good to know still. :)